# Подключение из Delphi через драйвер к MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, adoconnection

Хочу подключиться из Delphi к MySQL
скачал mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.7-winx64.msi
Установил. Завёл Delphi XE, но в списке "Создание нового источника данных" данный драйвер в списке не присутствует.
Как его ещё устанавливать?
Или где-то прописывать ручками, что-то надо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что Вы используете 64-разрядный драйвер. А, Delphi как была, так и сейчас осталась 32-разрядной. Поэтому Delphi его и не "видит".

Проблема обычно решается установкой 32-разрядного драйвера.

*P.S. Для версии XE2 и выше это замечание также актуально. 64-разрядный там, по сути, только компилятор под Win64. Сама IDE по прежнему 32-разрядная и "видит" только 32-разрядные драйвера.*

Comment: И работать с 32-разрядными драйверами в 64-битной системе нужно не из панели управления, а ручками запуская `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbccad32.exe`

Comment: @kami, странно, но у меня в ОС нет такого файла.

Comment: @Streletz, так как тогда быть для разработки приложений под 64-битные ОСи?

Answer (score -1):

Все зависит от целевой платформы 32 ли 64 бит и ***типа подключения***. Если используется dbGo (TADOConnection) тогда для каждой (32/64) нужно устанавливать свой **ODBC Connector**. И вручную создавать пользовательские, файловые или системные DSN выбрав соответсвенно драйвер MySQL. Но поставщиком данных нужно все равно выбирать **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC!**

А вот с использованием DbExpress или FireDAC  все не так однозначно. IDE может сильно ругаться приблизительно такими словами:

> DBX error: Driver could not be properly initialized Client library May
>   be missing, of the wrong version, May be missing from the driver or
>   the system path...

или

> [FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]=314, Cannot load vendor library [libmysql.dll, or libmysqld.dll]. The system cannot find the file specified.

Все дело в том, что **нужна сответствующая библиотека LIBMYSQL.DLL/LIBMYSQLD.DLL** ***причем соответствующей версии и для сервера и особенно для IDE!*** (для последнего - нужно посмотреть версию \bin\dbxmys.dll). 
Об этом можно подробно посмотреть в [этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mRGAB4LsEE).
И опять же - 32/64 бит. Поместиь этот файл можно в любую папку обозначенную в системной переменной PATH. Обычно это c:\Windows\system32 (или c:\Windows\syswow64). В крайнем случае - в \bin вашей IDE (но это моветон, ИМХО)
Тогда настраиваете TSQLConnection.Driver (dbExpress) или TFDConnection.DriverName (FireDAC) и другие необходимые свойства.

Comment: Для ADO (dbGo) источник нужно создавать по крайней мере не в Delphi (она не увидит драйвера для x64). В прочем, об этом сказано выше в комментарии. Для FireDac можно спокойно положить dll драйвера в **любую** папку. Хоть в папку с программой. Просто нужно настроить компоненты. А, помещать драйвер в папку IDE, это действительно очень не хорошо.